# how to change Symbol to other symbol?

Tags: replacement, symbols

I have

```
Input =a**b**c
```

I want to have output such as

```
{a,b,c}
```

So I want to change **->, but replace code does not work. How can I do it?

Comment: Look at `FullForm[Input]` and `FullForm[{a, b, c}]` and note what change you *really* want.

Comment: You can't use `Input` as a variable name because it is a reserved function. Try this: `input = a ** b ** c; Apply[List, input]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is recommended to look at the `FullForm` of the expression when you are trying to use a pattern and rules.

```
FullForm[a ** b ** c]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Seeing this it becomes easy to then:

```
a ** b ** c /. NonCommutativeMultiply -> List
(* {a, b, c} *)
```

Typically, shorter is better. Bob Hanlon suggested using:

```
List @@ (a ** b ** c)
(* {a, b, c} *)
```

which is another solution.